# php receives empty HTML Form on Mac

Tags: php, html, macos-mojave

Hello Guys I'm trying to set a HTML-PHP dev environment on my MacOS Mojave, I'm experiencing something like very basic issue on HTML-php dev.
1) I tried the following basic code to test my environment.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="POST" action="source.php">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>

and

<?php
//    var_dump($_POST["name"]);
if (isset ($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
}
else{
    echo "not data";
}
?>
```

when I submit the form, I have **no data** as result, seem like php receives an empty form.
When I run the following PHP code.

```
<?php
//    var_dump($_POST["name"]);
    $user = $_POST["name"];
    echo "$user";
?>
```

the result was *** Notice: Undefined index *** in line 3 of the php code.
I run this code with the same result on two Mac's environments (MAMP and local Mac' environment (set up apache and php)) . 
The same code is running find on my friends Windows environment. I need to understand what is wrong on my Mac. is it a system or config issue?
I haven't found similar issue on the web forum yet.

Comment: "when I submit the form, I have no data as result, seem like php receives an empty form." — Does it render *not data* or nothing at all?

Comment: It rends ***no data*** when I run the first php

Comment: Try using `var_dump($_POST)`, what does it say after submitting your form?

Comment: I tried var_dump($_POST) the result was ***null***

Comment: I mean php returned ***null***

Comment: var_dump($_REQUEST); will give any var sent can you try this?

Comment: php returns ***array (size=0) empty***

Comment: Now when I use local environment (default php and apache ), I no longer have this issue. moreover, when phpstorm is using to run the code error message point out (same as described before).